# How to only show one table view for a UISearchDisplayController implementation

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am presently using a default configuration of the UISearchDisplayController build in Storyboard, where I dragged the UISearchBar and SearchDisplayController onto an existing `UITableViewController`. Because it was dragged onto the TableViewController, there are **two** tables that I am managing - the `self.tableView`, and `self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView`.

What I would like to accomplish is to only show the `tableView` as the default table when a user opens this view, as well as reflected to show the user's search. As illustration (taken from a RW [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view)):

[image]

What I would want to achieve is that, as you are typing the word "egg", the `tableView` of RecipeBookVC would get rid of the rows without "egg", so you are left with the results viewed in `self.tableview` without having to see it from the `resultsTableView`. (Preferably also without hiding the Navigation Bar, so the search feels more like a "filter" rather than a search)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you actually need a Search Display Controller here. All you need is a table view (probably a `UITableViewController`) and `UISearchBar`. The table view displays the contents of an array containing the data. Whenever the search query changes, you update that array accordingly, and reload the tableView to display the updated array data. This will give you the filtering feel that you want.

To display the data in the table view you'd use

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and to get the query as the user types you'd use

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

After you've filtered the array that is the data source, you call `[self.tableView reloadData]`.

I went ahead and whipped together [a sample project](https://github.com/kevinjuneja/filter-table-example) with the methods implemented, so it's a little more clear what I mean. Hope this works out for ya.

Comment: This is really fantastic - thanks for whipping this up and showing me how to do it! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hey @kevin, just wanted to say that this is such a helpful project that I keep on coming back to it. Great job dude.

Comment: @daspianist glad to hear it! :)

Comment: Wanted to let you know that this is one project and question that I keep on coming back to, even after all this time. Thanks Kevin!